Where can I find documentation on Ubuntu 'onboard' onscreen keyboard custom layouts?
I don't mean a layout of a hardware keyboard, but the Ubuntu 'onboard' app which is an on screen keyboard in Ubuntu.
On Ubuntu 22.04 / 24.04 I can use onboard which is an excellent on screen keyboard.
But when I want to change the layout in the /usr/share/onboard/*.onboard files to set some keys on different places, I can only remove existing keys.
E.g. the standard Compact keyboard but with Esc + function keys above it or a Phone keyboard with digit row above it.
But when I move or add keys in the text file (which is actually xml) it does not show the changes when I reload the changed .onboard file.
I cannot find any documentation on this online, even not in Ubuntu documentation or wiki.
Does anybody know where I can fond documentation on this format ?
